# How do I show changes in my SQL table when I combined the values using GROUP BY?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I have this database table named Store_Data and I show three columns in the JTable.

Here are the columns:

1. NUMBERS
2. AMOUNT
3. DATE

How do I show the other columns in the jtable? The other columns are missing

[image]

I managed to obtain combined values using this SQL command, "SELECT NUMBERS, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Store_Data GROUP BY NUMBERS", and I managed show it in the JTable.

However, In the JTable I only see the column NUMBERS and another column showing all the sum of the AMOUNT values. I don't see the other columns in the Jtable.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
private JTable showRecords(Connection con)
{

    try
    {
        column.clear();
        data.clear();

        _stmt = con.createStatement();

        //String getColumn = "SELECT * FROM APP.NYPMTRIPLESTRAIGHT";

        /*this is only a test*/
        String test = "SELECT NUMBERS, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM Store_Data GROUP BY NUMBERS";

        ResultSet rs = _stmt.executeQuery(test);

        //this will collect the data from the database
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        //this will count all the columns from 
        int column_count = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for(int j = 1; j <= column_count; j++)
        {
            column.add(metaData.getColumnName(j));
        }

        while(rs.next())
        {

            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

            for(int i = 1; i <= column_count; i++)
            {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(i));
            }

            data.add(vector);
        }

        _records = new JTable(data, column);

        return _records;

    } catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
    }

    return _records;
}
```

NOTE: I know it is wrong to use Vector. I am only using it for testing.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @Multisync How do I show the other columns in the jtable? The other columns are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query sums all the values of AMOUNT and displays the sum using a Group by clause.

Group by will group similar values into one entity based on the functions used. ["sum" in your case].

You need to get the numbers and amount from your database simply

```
SELECT NUMBERS, AMOUNT FROM APP.NYPMTRIPLESTRAIGHT;
```

then display the resultset data in your JTable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.NUMBERS, 
  CONCAT(YEAR(T1.DATE) , '-' , MONTH(t1.DATE) , '-' ,DAY(t1.DATE)) as DATE, 
  SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT 
FROM table1 t1 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

And here you have the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1eda8/2)

Comment: I tried using that command you gave me and it was the same as the first image I posted above.

Comment: Ok so, I think you want to get the date too but grouping by day, am I right?

Comment: Yes, grouping by day and also time if possible. I was able to get the NUMBERS and AMOUNT column grouped but I guess with DATE is not possible because I am using a TIME STAMP value for the DATE column.